# Change post type depending on shortcode

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode

Is it possible to use 2 shortcodes with the same
function and change only the post type in the function
depending on what shortcode it is?

For instance, when I use `all_faq` shortcode the post type should be Faq. When I use `wordpress_faq` then the post type should be `wp-Faq`. It works now but is it possible to make the code shorter in one function? Like if `all_faq` is used change post type to `faq` and else if `wordpress faq` is used change post type to `wp-faq`.

```
//shortcode NORMAL FAQ
add_shortcode( 'all_faq', 'display_custom_post_type' );
function display_custom_post_type(){
$args = array(

    'post_type' => 'Faq',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1'
);

$string = '';
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $query->have_posts() ){
    $string .= '<div class="container-fluid">';
    $string .= '<div class="grid-container">';
    while( $query->have_posts() ){
        $query->the_post();
            $string .= '<div class="sub-grid">';
            $string .= '<div class="faq-shortcode-title">' . get_the_title() . '</div>';
            $string .= '<div class="faq-shortcode-content">' . get_the_content() . '</div>';
            $string .= '</div>';
        }
    $string .= '</div>';
    $string .= '</div>';
}
wp_reset_postdata();
return $string;
}

//shortcode WORDPRESS FAQ
add_shortcode( 'wordpress_faq', 'display_wordpress_faq' );
function display_wordpress_faq(){
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'wp-Faq',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1'
);

$string = '';
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $query->have_posts() ){
    $string .= '<div class="container-fluid">';
    $string .= '<div class="grid-container">';
    while( $query->have_posts() ){
        $query->the_post();
            $string .= '<div class="sub-grid">';
            $string .= '<div class="faq-shortcode-title">' . get_the_title() . '</div>';
            $string .= '<div class="faq-shortcode-content">' . get_the_content() . '</div>';
            $string .= '</div>';
        }
    $string .= '</div>';
    $string .= '</div>';
}
wp_reset_postdata();
return $string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the callback function has 3 parameters and the 3rd is the tag name :

```
add_shortcode( 'all_faq', 'commonFunction' );
add_shortcode( 'wordpress_faq', 'commonFunction' );


function commonFunction($attr, $content, $tag) {

    $cores = [
        "all_faq" => "Faq",
        "wordpress_faq" => "wp-Faq",
    ];


    $args = array(
        'post_type' => $cores[$tag],
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1'
    );


    // ...

}
```

Comment: MUCH better solution than mine. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could reverse the problem. 
What you need is simply add an argument to your shortcode and this way, you can have only one function and one shortcode.
You could have something like that at the beginning of you function :

```
$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'posttype' => 'Faq'
), $atts, 'all_faq' );

$args = array(

    'post_type' => $atts['posttype'],
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1'
);
```

Then, you can use your shortcode with a new parameter : `[all_faq posttype="Faq"]`

Hope that helps.